# Apps showing as subwebs

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm listing the subwebs for users in an SharePoint app. The thing is that the app also is showing my sharepoint apps as subwebs, how come?

Ex:

- Subweb #1
- Subweb #2
- App

Code:

```
                var context;
                var appContextSite;
                var factory;

                context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
                factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
                context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);

                appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

                this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
                this.subWebs = this.web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

                context.load(this.subWebs);

                context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {

                    var enumSubWebs = this.subWebs.getEnumerator();


                        while (enumSubWebs.moveNext()) {
                            var subWeb = enumSubWebs.get_current();

                            $scope.subWebs.push({
                                title: subWeb.get_title()
                            });

                            $scope.$apply();
                        }
                }),
                    Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                        alert('Request failed.' + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                    })
                );
```

Comment: The app web of a SharePoint app is actually created as a subweb on the web where the app is installed (but hidden from the GUI)

Answer (score 2):

The special website to which the app is deployed is called an app web. The website to which the app is installed is called the host web. Although the app web has its own isolated domain, it is in the same site collection as the host web. (One exception to this rule is when the app is installed with tenant scope. In that scenario, the app web is in the site collection of the corporate app catalog.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Didn't know that it was created as a subweb. Solved it with comparing the subwebs url with the hosturl and filtering out the apps that way.